# Connection error in connecting SQL Server with Spark Scala

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark

Getting error in connecting SQL Server with Spark Scala.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Main extends App{

  // Create dataframe on top of SQLServer database table

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testings").master("local[*]").config("configuration key", "configuration value").getOrCreate

  val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver" ,"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") //com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://23.96.125.13:1288;databaseName=InsightRepl")    //"url", "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXX.com:port;databaseName=xxx
    .option("dbtable","dpvHstGndTableTurn")
    .option("user", "********")
    .option("password","*********")
    .load()
 jdbcDF.show(5)

}
```

Comment: Add mssql-jdbc dependency to your project. If you are using sbt, add something like, libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.2.0.jre8".

Comment: name := "demo5"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

val sparkVersion ="2.4.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion

)